# Why does console keeps saying "uber-jar-6.5.5 seems corrupted"

Tags: aem, pom.xml

I was installing my project from IntelliJ to aem using this command (mvn clean install -PautoInstall) and I keep having this error

The JAR/ZIP file (C:\Users....m2\repository\com\adobe\aem\uber-jar\6.5.5\uber-jar-6.5.5.jar) seems corrupted, error: error in opening zip file

I have already tried deleting and downloading the uber-jar but to no avail.

Here is my Core Pom.xml

4.0.0

com.startsite
startsite
1.0-SNAPSHOT
../pom.xml

```
<artifactId>startsite.core</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<name>Start Site - Core</name>
<description>Core bundle for Start Site</description>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <!-- Import any version of javax.inject, to allow running on multiple versions of AEM -->
                    <Import-Package>javax.inject;version=0.0.0,*</Import-Package>
                    <Sling-Model-Packages>
                        com.startsite.core
                    </Sling-Model-Packages>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- OSGi Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.annotation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Other Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
        <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
        <classifier>apis</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.sling.models.api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
        <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.day.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>day.commons.datasource.poolservice</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: try running maven with `--verbose` flag, that should tell you a little more.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found an alternate solution to solve this problem. I used Eclipse neon instead of the usual eclipse and intellij. Newly created project now works except the one that I have previously compiled on Intellij and eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your local **~/.m2** repository and try again.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does console keeps saying "uber-jar-6.5.5 seems corrupted"

It will be saying that **because** the file is corrupt ... or not a JAR file at all.

Take a look at what is actually in the (supposed) JAR file:

- Use `jar -tvf <pathname>` to list the index.  That should tell you if the file is corrupt, etcetera.
- On linux, use `file <pathname>` to try to determine what file type it really is.
- If it is text, look at it using a text editor.

(My guess is that the file is not downloading properly.  My second guess is that what you actually have there is an HTML document containing an error message from the failed download.  If this is the case, there should be some clues in the error message as to why the download is failing.)

Comment: Haven't tried this, will return to this comment when it works

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pom. I see the uber-jar declared twice, remove the first and keep only the one with the version on it. Also, the uber-jar should have the scope as provided:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
            <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Then, delete the uber-jar from your m2 folder and execute `mvn -U clean install -PautoInstall`

Comment: tried it already, still throws the same error